# How to export a excel template file using golang and Go-echo?

Tags: excel, postgresql, csv, go

I need to export a excel file of a specific template and import it back to insert into postgres as rows.
I don't know how to do this using go-echo and gorm.
Can someone tell me how i can do that?

Comment: Add it on static, then hit it

Comment: @RahmatFathoni Can u please explain a bit more, I am new to Go.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First [read the Excel data](https://github.com/qax-os/excelize), then map the data to Struct, and finally write it to PostgreSQL through gorm,I don't know what go-echo does here

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Thanks @Ivan, sorry for the clarification here, I am writing an Api that takes an excel file and inserts the data into Postgres using go-echo that's why i mentioned go-echo there. Thanks for the response.